# Overflow-x scroll with visible overflow-y causing hidden content in absolute-positioned div

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

**Note**: This is not a duplicate question; I have checked every related questions on stackoverflow.

I have a `div` with `overflow-x: scroll`, and I want the `overflow-y` to be visible. Inside this `div`, I have another `div` with a position set to `absolute`. However, I'm facing an issue where the content inside the absolute-positioned `div` is hidden when there's overflow in the `y` direction.

Here's a simplified reactjs generated version of my HTML and CSS structure:

```css
      .zooming-bar {
        width: 100%;
        padding: 2px 0;
        background: hsl(0, 0%, 40%);
        position: relative;
        cursor: move;
        display: flex;
        height: 100px;
        overflow-x: scroll;
        overflow-y: visible;
      }

      .scrollable-bar {
        width: 100%;
        cursor: pointer;
        margin: 0 auto;
        position: relative;
        top: 30px;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        height: 25px;
        margin-left: 0;
      }
      .buttons-block {
        position: relative;
        top: 50px;
      }

      .buttons-group {
        height: 30px;
      }
      .flex-wrap {
        flex-wrap: wrap;
      }
      .sub-segment-wrapper {
        margin-left: 0;
        top: -55px;
      }

      .segment-wrapper {
        margin-left: 2px;
        margin-right: 2px;
        margin-top: 2px;
        display: flex;
        width: 100%;
        height: fit-content;
        position: absolute;
      }
      .button-segment {
        color: #000;
        text-align: center;
        font-family: "Poppins Regular";
        font-size: 14px;
        font-style: normal;
        font-weight: 400;
        background-color: #ff7e64;
        height: 20px;
        width: 100%;
        margin-right: 2px;
        position: relative;
        border: 2px solid transparent;
        line-height: 15px;
      }

      .button-card-task-description {
        height: 25px;
        padding-top: 10px;
      }
      .button-info-card {
        position: absolute;
        background: #ffffff;
        bottom: 35px;
        z-index: 5;
        width: 85%;
        border-radius: 5px;
        right: 0;
        filter: drop-shadow(0px 0px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25));
        border-left: 12px solid #f2f2f2;
        padding: 5px;
      }
      .button-info-card:after {
        content: "";
        position: absolute;
        border-left: 10px solid transparent;
        border-right: 10px solid transparent;
        top: 100%;
        border-top: 12px solid #ffffff;
        margin-top: 0;
        right: 25px;
      }
      .button-label-inside {
        z-index: 2;
        position: relative;
        padding: 0 5px;
      }
      .content-pane {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: row;
        justify-content: space-between;
        background: hsl(240deg 19.32% 67.79%);
        height: 40px;
        align-items: center;
      }
      .content-pane > div {
        margin: 3px;
      }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Example code</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div>
      <div class="content-pane">
        <div>Content1</div>
        <div>Content2</div>
        <div>Content3</div>
        <div>Content4</div>
        <div>Content5</div>
      </div>
      <div class="content-pane">
        <div>Content1</div>
        <div>Content2</div>
        <div>Content3</div>
        <div>Content4</div>
        <div>Content5</div>
      </div>

      <div class="zooming-bar">
        <div class="scrollable-bar">
          <div class="buttons-block">
            <div
              class="segment-wrapper flex-wrap buttons-group"
              style="left: 10%"
            >
              <div
                class="segment-wrapper flex-wrap sub-segment-wrapper button-main"
                style="left: 0%; width: 15%"
              >
                <div class="button-segment segment-button-main ">
                  <span class="button-info-card"
                    ><span class="button-card-task-description">
                      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.
                      Tempora, nihil eaque? Sequi ab, magni ducimus qui corporis
                      natus repellendus. Officiis eum architecto commodi maxime
                      illo iste aliquam enim mollitia odit?
                    </span></span
                  ><span class="button-label"
                    ><span class="button-label-inside">Button Label</span></span
                  >
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="buttons-block">
            <div
              class="segment-wrapper flex-wrap buttons-group"
              style="left: 40%"
            >
              <div
                class="segment-wrapper flex-wrap sub-segment-wrapper button-main"
                style="left: 0%; width: 25%"
              >
                <div class="button-segment segment-button-main ">
                  <span class="button-info-card"
                    ><span class="button-card-task-description">
                      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.
                      Tempora, nihil eaque? Sequi ab, magni ducimus qui corporis
                      natus repellendus. Officiis eum architecto commodi maxime
                      illo iste aliquam enim mollitia odit?
                    </span></span
                  ><span class="button-label"
                    ><span class="button-label-inside">Button Label</span></span
                  >
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="buttons-block">
            <div
              class="segment-wrapper flex-wrap buttons-group"
              style="left: 70%"
            >
              <div
                class="segment-wrapper flex-wrap sub-segment-wrapper button-main"
                style="left: 0%; width: 25%"
              >
                <div class="button-segment segment-button-main ">
                  <span class="button-info-card"
                    ><span class="button-card-task-description">
                      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.
                      Tempora, nihil eaque? Sequi ab, magni ducimus qui corporis
                      natus repellendus. Officiis eum architecto commodi maxime
                      illo iste aliquam enim mollitia odit?
                    </span></span
                  ><span class="button-label"
                    ><span class="button-label-inside">Button Label</span></span
                  >
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="buttons-block">
            <div
              class="segment-wrapper flex-wrap buttons-group"
              style="left: 110%"
            >
              <div
                class="segment-wrapper flex-wrap sub-segment-wrapper button-main"
                style="left: 0%; width: 25%"
              >
                <div class="button-segment segment-button-main ">
                  <span class="button-info-card"
                    ><span class="button-card-task-description">
                      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.
                      Tempora, nihil eaque? Sequi ab, magni ducimus qui corporis
                      natus repellendus. Officiis eum architecto commodi maxime
                      illo iste aliquam enim mollitia odit?
                    </span></span
                  ><span class="button-label"
                    ><span class="button-label-inside">Button Label</span></span
                  >
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

I want the content inside the `.zooming-bar` to be visible. However, the content is hidden.

How can I achieve the desired behavior of having `overflow-x` as scroll while keeping `overflow-y` as visible, allowing the content inside the `.zooming-bar` to be fully visible in `y` direction?

See below screenshot of how the popup should look like, while the scroll down is working:
[image]

**Last note:** I want that hidden part of the popup to be shown over the above content, and I don't want to add extra padding or margin to the related div(s).

Comment: Why not add a snippet to your question that demonstrates the behavior you are seeing (and want to fix)?

Comment: @ControlAltDel Please take a moment to review the source code I've just appended. It serves as a demonstration of the HTML and CSS components that are currently causing me difficulties.

Comment: _"Note: This is not a duplicate question"_ - it _kinda_ is though, because your problem appears to stem from the same fact discussed under https://stackoverflow.com/q/6421966/1427878 - so at least for the explanation as to _why_ what you got doesn't work, this would do.

Comment: I guess you could try to work around the situation, if you placed the scroll bar on the top-most div container instead - and then applied `position:sticky` to those `.content-pane` elements, so that they _stay_ in their position, when the whole rest gets scrolled sideways ...?

Comment: https://css-tricks.com/popping-hidden-overflow/ also handles a very similar issue.

Comment: @CBroe thank you for you comments and tip, I just checked that question on my very first search results, that's actually not helping in my case.
and regarding your tip I just wanted to mention that I am restricted to this html structure, I only have interaction with the elements through CSS and JS.

Comment: JS can still manipulate the DOM structure that results from "god-given, unchangeable" HTML ...

Comment: Looking at the image you posted, I would advise you to just use Element.title

Comment: @ControlAltDel if by Element.title you mean adding title attribute for my span then I should say, there will be some more inline elements inside that info-card span, so I can't use title attribute.

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <style>
      .zooming-bar {
        width: 100%;
        padding: 2px 0;
        background: hsl(0, 0%, 40%);
        position: relative;
        cursor: move;
        display: flex;
        z-index: 2;
        height: 100px;
      }

      .scrollable-bar {
        width: 100%;
        cursor: pointer;
        margin: 0 auto;
        position: relative;
        top: 30px;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        height: 25px;
        margin-left: 0;
      }
      .buttons-block {
        position: relative;
        top: 50px;
      }

      .buttons-group {
        height: 30px;
      }
      .flex-wrap {
        flex-wrap: wrap;
      }
      .sub-segment-wrapper {
        margin-left: 0;
        top: -55px;
      }

      .segment-wrapper {
        margin-left: 2px;
        margin-right: 2px;
        margin-top: 2px;
        display: flex;
        width: 100%;
        height: fit-content;
        position: absolute;
      }
      .button-segment {
        color: #000;
        text-align: center;
        font-family: "Poppins Regular";
        font-size: 14px;
        font-style: normal;
        font-weight: 400;
        background-color: #ff7e64;
        height: 20px;
        width: 100%;
        margin-right: 2px;
        position: relative;
        border: 2px solid transparent;
        line-height: 15px;
      }

      .button-card-task-description {
        height: 25px;
        padding-top: 10px;
      }
      .button-info-card {
        position: absolute;
        background: #ffffff;
        bottom: 35px;
        z-index: 5;
        width: 85%;
        border-radius: 5px;
        right: 0;
        filter: drop-shadow(0px 0px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25));
        border-left: 12px solid #f2f2f2;
        padding: 5px;
      }
      .button-info-card:after {
        content: "";
        position: absolute;
        border-left: 10px solid transparent;
        border-right: 10px solid transparent;
        top: 100%;
        border-top: 12px solid #ffffff;
        margin-top: 0;
        right: 25px;
      }
      .button-label-inside {
        z-index: 2;
        position: relative;
        padding: 0 5px;
      }
      .content-pane {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: row;
        justify-content: space-between;
        background: hsl(240deg 19.32% 67.79%);
        height: 52px;
        align-items: center;
      }
      .content-pane > div {
        margin: 3px;
      }

      .test {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        position: relative;
        z-index: 1;
      }
      .overflow {
        overflow-x: scroll;
        overflow-y: visible;
      }
    </style>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Example code</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="overflow">
      <div class="test">
        <div class="content-pane">
          <div>Content1</div>
          <div>Content2</div>
          <div>Content3</div>
          <div>Content4</div>
          <div>Content5</div>
        </div>
        <div class="content-pane">
          <div>Content1</div>
          <div>Content2</div>
          <div>Content3</div>
          <div>Content4</div>
          <div>Content5</div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="zooming-bar">
        <div class="scrollable-bar">
          <div class="buttons-block">
            <div
              class="segment-wrapper flex-wrap buttons-group"
              style="left: 10%"
            >
              <div
                class="segment-wrapper flex-wrap sub-segment-wrapper button-main"
                style="left: 0%; width: 15%"
              >
                <div class="button-segment segment-button-main">
                  <span class="button-info-card"
                    ><span class="button-card-task-description">
                      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.
                      Tempora, nihil eaque? Sequi ab, magni ducimus qui corporis
                      natus repellendus. Officiis eum architecto commodi maxime
                      illo iste aliquam enim mollitia odit?
                    </span></span
                  ><span class="button-label"
                    ><span class="button-label-inside">Button Label</span></span
                  >
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="buttons-block">
            <div
              class="segment-wrapper flex-wrap buttons-group"
              style="left: 40%"
            >
              <div
                class="segment-wrapper flex-wrap sub-segment-wrapper button-main"
                style="left: 0%; width: 25%"
              >
                <div class="button-segment segment-button-main">
                  <span class="button-info-card"
                    ><span class="button-card-task-description">
                      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.
                      Tempora, nihil eaque? Sequi ab, magni ducimus qui corporis
                      natus repellendus. Officiis eum architecto commodi maxime
                      illo iste aliquam enim mollitia odit?
                    </span></span
                  ><span class="button-label"
                    ><span class="button-label-inside">Button Label</span></span
                  >
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="buttons-block">
            <div
              class="segment-wrapper flex-wrap buttons-group"
              style="left: 70%"
            >
              <div
                class="segment-wrapper flex-wrap sub-segment-wrapper button-main"
                style="left: 0%; width: 25%"
              >
                <div class="button-segment segment-button-main">
                  <span class="button-info-card"
                    ><span class="button-card-task-description">
                      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.
                      Tempora, nihil eaque? Sequi ab, magni ducimus qui corporis
                      natus repellendus. Officiis eum architecto commodi maxime
                      illo iste aliquam enim mollitia odit?
                    </span></span
                  ><span class="button-label"
                    ><span class="button-label-inside">Button Label</span></span
                  >
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="buttons-block">
            <div
              class="segment-wrapper flex-wrap buttons-group"
              style="left: 110%"
            >
              <div
                class="segment-wrapper flex-wrap sub-segment-wrapper button-main"
                style="left: 0%; width: 25%"
              >
                <div class="button-segment segment-button-main">
                  <span class="button-info-card"
                    ><span class="button-card-task-description">
                      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.
                      Tempora, nihil eaque? Sequi ab, magni ducimus qui corporis
                      natus repellendus. Officiis eum architecto commodi maxime
                      illo iste aliquam enim mollitia odit?
                    </span></span
                  ><span class="button-label"
                    ><span class="button-label-inside">Button Label</span></span
                  >
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

This is a working solution of the code you have provided. I divided your code into two divs and gave them z-index property accordingly. Also I removed the scroll from zooming-bar and added it onto the main div. Hope this helps you out. Let me know if there are any problems in this.

Comment: The content part above the zooming-bar should not be scrollable due that overflow is added for zooming-bar class.